# Hadoop Streaming - Too many input params

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming

I am running a map reduce job via hadoop streaming but it gives me an error "too many params". The problem lies in the input where I am passing more than 1500 directories in input argument. I cannot reduce the number of input files.

Any suggestions.

Comment: Are you sure its with the 1500 directories ? the number of inputs eligible should be INTEGER.MAX (in java) which would a very large number (2^31 -1). This comes from the source code of hadoop streaming jar - StreamJob.java.

Can you share the complete error details ?

Comment: Well I am using hadoop streaming and it complains for the number of command line args.

Comment: Swapnil - Could you share more details like the exact command and exact error message.

Comment: hadoop streamjar -input dira,dirb,dirc.........

Comment: The format for multiple inputs is :  hadoop jar hadoop-streaming.jar -input '/user/foo/dir1' -input '/user/foo/dir2' ...

Comment: you can also do it the way i specified. if I use it your way, I will have to do a lot of parsing in my logic and the statement gets too ugly. Though i have been able to solve it by moving all the files in one go to single folder and use it as input dir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always use wildcard to select many files without need to explicitly list them.

Comment: The files are from different directories and I am already using a wild card to fetch the files from those directories. So i should rather say I have 1500 different directories and then multiple files inside those directories.

Comment: I see - could you use wild card for multiple directories?

Comment: No I cannot.. I am looking for any override property that can take more than 1000 params as the input argument. Else I will have to split the directory list into 2 and run the MR job twice